# Android Activity Stack Question

Tags: android

My android program has 4 activities:
A -> B -> C -> D

When activity C starts activity D, activity C closes. (The onStop() method is called).
Is there a way to tell why it is closing?

Comment: if you are using startActivity() it does not close. it hides C. And when D finishes, C resumes.

Comment: Both startActivity() and startActivityForResult() end up closing activity C. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If C is no longer visible once D starts (e.g D is full screen), then C will be stopped per the standard activity lifecycle:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife

Comment: I see, so onStop() being called doesn't necessarily mean my activity is being destroyed. Although when D closes, it goes back to B.  Is there something I can call from D to go straight back to C?

Comment: so when you hit the back button from D, it skips C and goes back to B?   That is unexpected, there should be a linear progression based on the activity stack... http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html#applications_activities

Comment: On further inspection, activity C is being destroyed when it calls D. Are there any ways to check how or what is destroying it?

Comment: how are you starting D?  are you sure you aren't calling finish() in C?

Comment: No, I'm not calling finish() or anything like that from C. I'm starting D using startActivityForResult(). As a side note, Activity C is started from B also using startActivityForResult(). When D finishes, execution returns to the onActivityResult() method of B since C is already destroyed.

Comment: @FoppyOmega: It's quite strange that when you hit Back being on D you don't get to C. I am with Karl R - can you show the code where you start the C and also where you start the D? Do you use any additional explicit flags when starting C (NO_HISTORY, for instance)?

Comment: Got it! Activity C wasn't actually being destroyed. The Panel on it was being destroyed with an onSurfaceDestroy() and in there I had a finish(). I just confused the two destroy methods.    Thanks for the help guys. Karl, I'll mark your answer correct since you answered my original question correctly with some good information.

Comment: Thanks Foppy, glad you figured it out